# MySQL LIKE после агрегатной выборки

Tags: mysql

Такой запрос

```
SELECT sum(views) FROM `stat` WHERE user_id = 1002 AND views LIKE '%777%' GROUP BY date
```

В таблице, в колонке views значения 777 нет. Это суммарное значение. Как в этом случае применить LIKE?

```
 date      | SUM(views)
--------------------
2019-01-31 | 525
2019-01-30 | 777
2019-01-29 | 128
```

Comment: после group by `having sum(views)=777`

Comment: И не надо применять like к числам. он используется только для поиска части строки